# Rotating photos to show images in landscape with QGIS Importphoto Plugin?

Tags: qgis

I am working in QGIS to build a database of historical photos. Using the importphotos plugin I have the images in my map but when displaying I have to rotate those taken in portrait view (Dims: 2448 width x 3264 height) when all other shots taken in landscape (3264 width x 2448 height) stay rotated correctly. Is there an adjustment to the base code or some fix to ensure all images are rotated correctly?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! Are the photos rotated correctly if you view them directly from your disk? And how do you view the photos in QGIS? With the Photo Clicker from the Import photos plugin?

Comment: In Layer properties go to symbology - there you have a field named rotation. Use a data-defined override - maybe you already have a field in your attribute table that marks each photo as landscape or portrait? If not, you have to (manually) create one. E.g.: add 0 (for photos that don't need rotation) and 90 (for photos to rotate) in the fields and then add this field for data-driven rotation-angle.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions guys. I could not find a solution normally so thought reloading old windows viewer or using photo app to move the pic around might correct it. It didn't but had to work through Infraview by rotating one way then back to vertical. Fixed them all. Just thought there might have been a line I could add to the importphoto plugin to show images vertically correctly as they are shown normally in Photo app or Photo viewer.